# Installing Ubuntu 16.04 on Dell Inspiron 5482

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, dell, nvme

I am new to Ubuntu and trying to install it on my laptop.
I get through the stages fine until the "installation type" stage where the [partition is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDSs8.png).
I get three buttons, `+`, `-`, and `change...`. When I press the `+` or `change...` it terminates the installation and when I press the `-`, it prompts a message `No root file system is defined,  please correct this from partition menu.`

Do you have an idea what should I do?

Comment: Run gparted and see what is there.

Answer (score 0):

if you are in dual boot, you can check in Windows the hard disk partition, and if you don't know any clue about what's going on right now, you can try to see in the internet about your problem or the installation.

Comment: Thanks, I'll dig dipper :)

Answer (score 0):

So I dug deeper, and as it turns out, my computer was provided with an NVMe storage (hard drive). To install Ubuntu on an NVMe storage I needed to change some settings in the BIOS following [this article](https://www.dell.com/support/article/il/en/ildhs1/sln299303/loading-ubuntu-on-systems-using-pcie-m2-drives?lang=en).
It worked fine though I couldn't install it in dual boot mode, luckily I could let go of my Windows 10 because I don't work much with MS Office.

Here is another [helpful article](https://www.dell.com/support/article/il/en/ildhs1/sln151664/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-dell-pc?lang=en) I found along the way which deals with installing Ubuntu on dell computers.

I hope it will help others,